# Use IPython in Emacs' python-mode

Tags: python, emacs

I would like to set IPython as my default interpreter when using python-mode in Emacs.  Currently, whenever I open `.py` Emacs opens the buffer and a regular Python interpreter.  How can I configure python-mode to use IPython by default?

Comment: in python-mode.el M-x customize RET py-shell-name; also shebang is honored and commands like py-execute-buffer-ipython exist